# More efficient groupBy scala, avoid GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: scala, collections, parallel-processing, garbage-collection, scala-2.12

This question is unrelated to Spark, and I'm working on scala 2.12 so I don't have access to groupMap or groupMapReduce.

I currently have code like the following

```scala
    val customerTrips = customerData.toList.par.groupBy(c => c.customerId)  // map between customerId and their trips

    val res = (
      customerData
        .toList.par
        .flatMap(
          c1 =>
            customerData(c1.tripId)
              .map(c2 => intermediateSchema(customer1Id=c1.customerId,customer2Id=c2.customerId, date=c1.date))
              .withFilter(row => row.customer1Id < row.customer2Id)
        )
      )  // create a list of two customers on the same trip
    println(res.size)  // size is about 5,000,000

    val res2 = res.groupBy(row => (row.customer1Id, row.customer2Id))  // GC overhead limit exceeded here
    println(res2.size) 

    val res3 = res2.mapValues(_.size)  // trying to get the number of trips shared between customers
```

I tried to annotate where I'm getting the error above with the groupBy. I'm pretty new to scala and don't know if there is a preferred/better method of doing this. I'd like to keep the aggregation parallel so I don't thinks something like foldLeft is what I'm looking for. If the only option is to increase the heap size (I have it set to the default 1.33GB) or change the garbage collector let me know.

Comment: `groupBy` is not parallel, so you can just use `foldLeft` you may take a look to the source code of `groupMapReduce` for inspiration.

Comment: Ah wait, I just realized you are using the parallel collections module. Don't they have a `accumulate` or something like that is like a parallel `foldLeft`?

Comment: How much of the memory space does `customerTrips` use?

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for the questions. What I ended up doing was using `aggregate` to a `Map`. I tried using `ParMap` but kept running into side-effects problems. I think `Map` worked well, the aggregation is still parallelized even though the end structure is not. If anyone has advice for controlling the side effects problems let me know. I can offer up more information about the method if you're interested. FWIW I tried a `foldleft` implementation and it was incredibly slow, taking over 5 minutes before I killed it. `aggregate` finished in 80seconds by comparison.